# Need advice on preparing custom dataset for PCA

Tags: python, pca

as mentioned above, i am currently working on a PCA face recognition project however, i came across an obstacle that i would like to seek advice on.

To begin, I am creating my own dataset so i currently have 10 pictures of 20 people, I have managed to extract out the image features using the following code:

```
        for img in os.listdir(path): #reiterate inside folder
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img),cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                x_data.append(img_array)
                y_data.append(class_num)
            except Exception as e:
                pass
```

the return on the x_data[0] gives me this

```
[[255 255 254 ... 255 254 255]
 [255 255 254 ... 254 255 255]
 [255 255 255 ... 255 253 255]
 ...
 [255 255 255 ...  71 215 254]
 [254 255 255 ...  60 209 255]
 [255 255 255 ...  55 210 255]]
```

however when I apply standardscalar to this x_data

`X_std = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X_train)`

i am returned with this error

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I believe its either because of the extra[] on each element or due to the dtype=uint8 as I have read but I have no clue as to how to proceed. I have tried to eliminate the extra [] but to no avail.

Can anyone advice me on this issue?

Furthermore, if my code can be improved, could you also give me some directions on how? 
Appreciate your time taken to help out in any way.

Comment: Where does `X_train` comes from?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try something like:

```
X_std = [StandardScaler().fit_transform(data) for data in x_data]
```

Would this achieve what you want?